# How to use PutFile in windows shared folder

Tags: linux, apache-nifi

Am trying to use NiFi's `putFile` to write into a windows mounted directory, first I used below command to mount the directory

```
sudo mount -t cifs //IP/export_path/ /home/exported_data/ -o username=user,password='pw',dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,nounix
```

and the file is written correctly but preceeded by dot `.` but then nifi throws an error stating that ...

```
Unable to remove temporary file /home/exported_data/.reject_2020-04-21.csv due to java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/exported_data/.reject_2020-04-21.csv: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/exported_data/.reject_2020-04-21.csv
```

I also tried to set properties in `putFile` like `Owner = nifi` and `Permissions = 777` but it didn't work

I think it could be related to permissions issue, but am not sure how to solve it

Comment: please show config of `putFile`

Comment: also edit your question and provide full error from log file. potentially there could be   some warnings before the error like `Could not set file permissions`. Note that linux systems try to set specific rights on dot `.` files.

Comment: I too have a problem with putFile to an NFS share, it causes file permissions to be "The requested security information is either unavailable or can't be displayed" in windows under security tab. No fix so far